How can I automate placing a large image in two adjacent pages so that it forms a two-page spread?
I'm making a pdf which is meant to be printed as a physical book, and I'd like to be able to place an image such that its evenly split between one odd page and its subsequent even page and seems as though it was drawn on a spread.
Below is an example of what I want to achieve; notice how bieces of the robots' scarf and limbs spill on the adjacent page.
I'm assuming what I'd need to do is place the image twice in different figure enviroenments and then line up the two images so the visible parts form a cohesive hole, but I'm not sure how to do that.


It is not clear what you need exactly. This answer show how split a conventional figure in two pages, but this is far of what you show.

Well yes what's going on here is way more complicated, but I already know how to do most of it. It's just that my version always has the image on a separate page, and I'd like to avoid that

Can you provide simplified code?

I'll try but it's kind of a problem: I'm using a very complex template for this work and I'm not sure about what I can "unplug" for readability.
your answer was already very helpful though.

You can work backwards, like so: a) work on a copy, b) uncomment all, but the graphics part (the one or few lines calling image), c) compile, which will fail, d) uncomment documentclass and document environment, compile again. e) continue gradual uncommenting, watching the first or two error messages, which guide you towards what’s missing. After a while you should have the bare necessary code. Cleanup, compile again as a check … ready to post ;-)

Have a look at the hvfloat package
